# QTP 11 Object Spy doesn't recognize any object below Browser.Page.WinObject

Tags: automation, qtp

[image]I recently switched from QTP 10 to 11 and now when I use Object Spy it doesn't recognize anything below Browser.Page.WinObject.  Meaning it recognizes that there is a browser and it has a window, but it won't read buttons. links etc.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which browser are you using (IE/Chrome/Firefox)? Also are you using a 64 bit browser? It could be that you're missing some patches for QTP11.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Internet Explorer 9 (IE9) was added to QTP11 by patch [QTPWEB_00078](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/FID/DOCUMENTUM_QTPWEB_00078).

You'll have to either install this patch or downgrade your browser to IE8.